# Jquery select /unselect works for first time not for subsequent clicks

Tags: jquery

```
$('#parent1').click(function () {
    if ($('#parent1').is(':checked')) {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', false);
    }
});
```

This function works but only first time even though its not part of document.ready(function).

Its not working for subsequent clicks ? Is there anything missing here ? Any help would be much appreciated.

All my child checkboxes are parent2,3,4,...15.

```
<c:forEach var="parent1" items="${model.list}"> 
    <form:checkbox path="list" value="${parent1.name}" label="${parent1.name}" /> 
</for:each>
```

Comment: you do not need "function() {" I guess

Comment: hey Erkaner, without function, it doesn't even work for first time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`, the **[behavior of `.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc)** is inconsistent.

```
$('#parent1').change(function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

**[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w1j1jgd1/)**

Comment: if i have to select only parent 2,3,4 instead of parent 5,6,7 ??

Comment: Can you show your HTML? Edit it using `Edit` link in the question. You canwrite it this way though `$('#parent2,#parent3,#parent4').prop('checked', this.checked);`